# Migrate track last imported time

Tags: 8, migrations

Which property should I set to save the last imported time in the migration map (SQL)?

I've seen that adding:

```
source:
  track_changes: true
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source

The hash is been calculated but no idea how to set the calculation of the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [setTrackLastImported](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21Migration.php/function/Migration%3A%3AsetTrackLastImported/8.5.x) to `TRUE`.

What I've done is create a new source plugin that extends the source plugin that I was using and set to true the last imported property.

```
/**
 * Source plugin that extends "url" source plugin and saves the last imported
 * date.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "url_last_import"
 * )
 */
class UrlLastImport extends Url {

public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MigrationInterface $migration) {
    $migration->setTrackLastImported(TRUE);
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $migration);
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The last import date for a migration is stored in the key_value store.

See `Drupal\migrate_tools\Controller\MigrationListBuilder.php` for an example on how to get the timestamp of the last import for a given migration:

```
  $migrate_last_imported_store = \Drupal::keyValue('migrate_last_imported');
  $last_imported = $migrate_last_imported_store->get($migration->id(), FALSE);
```

Next to the last imported timestamp it's also possible to get a timestamp for each row (with setTrackLastImported(), see `Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\id_map\Sql`).

Comment: The value retrieved is in milliseconds so make sure you divide by 1000. Example can be found in `modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Controller/MigrationListBuilder.php.`